# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,) c language sqlite3

Tags: c, sqlite

I am trying to create a cgi executable with sqlite3 with c. But I am getting the error EXC_BAD_ACCESS and I don't know what the problem is. My code:

main.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include "sqlite.h"

int callback(void *, int, char **, char **);

int main() {

    printf("Content-Type: text/html\n\n");

    sqlite_container *ptr = get_sql();

    char *sql_query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cars;"
                "CREATE TABLE Cars(Id INT, Name TEXT, Price INT);"
                "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(1, 'Audi', 52642);"
                "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(2, 'Mercedes', 57127);"
                "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(3, 'Skoda', 9000);"
                "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(4, 'Volvo', 29000);"
                "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(5, 'Bentley', 350000);"
                "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(6, 'Citroen', 21000);"
                "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(7, 'Hummer', 41400);"
                "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(8, 'Volkswagen', 21600);";

    int rc = sqlite3_exec(ptr->db, sql_query, 0, 0, 0);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to fetch data: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(ptr->db));
        sqlite3_close(ptr->db);

        return 1;
    }

    ptr = "SELECT * FROM Cars";

    rc = sqlite3_exec(ptr->db, sql_query, callback, 0, 0);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK ) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to select data\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(ptr->db));

        sqlite3_close(ptr->db);

        return 1;
    }

    sqlite3_close(ptr->db);

    printf("%s\n", sqlite3_libversion());

    return 0;
}

int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv,
             char **azColName) {

    NotUsed = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {

        printf("<pre>%s = %s</pre>\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

sqlite.h

```c
#pragma once
#include <sqlite3.h>

typedef struct {
    struct sqlite3 *db;
    int status;
} sqlite_container;

sqlite_container *get_sql();
```

sqlite.c

```c
#include "sqlite.h"
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "config.h"

sqlite_container* get_sql() {
    sqlite_container* container = malloc(sizeof(struct sqlite_container *));
    container->db = NULL;
    container->status = 0;

    int rc = sqlite3_open(DATABASEFILE, &container->db);
    container->status = rc;

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(container->db));
        sqlite3_close(container->db);
    }
    return container;
}
```

config.h

```c
#pragma once

#define DATABASEFILE "test.sql"
```

The debugger stops at main.c line 37

```c
rc = sqlite3_exec(ptr->db, sql_query, callback, 0, 0);
```

the error is for example `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2a205443454c45c4)`
but I cant find the address in the variables overview. Im using clion as editor.

Comment: With `malloc(sizeof(struct sqlite_container *))` you allocate memory for a ***pointer*** to a `struct sqlite_container`, when you should allocate memory for the structure object itself. Simple solution is to use the variable you define in the `sizeof` expression: `sqlite_container* container = malloc(sizeof *container);`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. In main.c i had the following:

```c
    ptr = "SELECT * FROM Cars";

    rc = sqlite3_exec(ptr->db, sql_query, callback, 0, 0);
```

and i override ptr from a struct into a string. When i changed the ptr to another variable the program was working again.

Note: I have tried out the suggestion from the comments and then i found the error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This should have been possible to catch by the compiler. It would have warned you that you're assigning pointers of the wrong type. If it doesn't, then you need to enable more warnings, and treat them as errors (which they too often are).